# Ошибка в поиске слов в строке

Tags: c++, строки

У меня 2 вопроса:

1. почему мне выдает ошибку substr: не является членом "std::vector<Book,std::allocator<_Ty>>" ?
2. в предпоследней строчке мне выдает ошибку не найден оператор "=". Мне надо его перегружать или где-то ошибка есть?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "BoolShelf.h"
#include "Book.h"
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, vector<string> & v)
{
    string temp;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        getline(is, temp);
        if (!is) break;
        v[i] = temp;
    }
    return is;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, vector<string> & v)
{
    for (auto i : v)
    {
        os << i;
        os << '\n';
    }
    return os;
}
bool func(string& s)
{
    if (s[0] == 'v')
        return true;
    else return false;
}

  void BookShelf::SaveBook()
{
      vector<string> v;
      vector<string>::iterator it = v.begin();
      while (it != v.end())
      {
          it = find_if(it, v.end(), func);
          if (it != v.end())
          {
              cout << *it << "\n";
              it++;
          }
      }

      ofstream f1("book.txt");
      if (!f1.is_open())
      {
          cout << "Ошибка открытия файла!" << endl;
      }
      else
      {
          cout << "Файл открыт!" << endl;
          v.resize(4);
         cin >> v;
         for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
              f1 << *it << "\n";
      }
      f1.close();
}

void BookShelf::LoadBook()
{
    vector<string> v;
    vector<string>::iterator it = v.begin();
    while (it != v.end())
    {
        it = find_if(it, v.end(), func);
        if (it != v.end())
        {
            cout << *it << "\n";
            it++;
        }
    }

    string tmp;
    ifstream f2("book.txt");
    if (f2.is_open())
    {
        while (!f2.end())
        {
            getline(f2, tmp);
            Book b(tmp);
            books.push_back(b);
        }
    }
    f2.close();

    for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
        cout << *it << "\n";
}

int BookShelf::Selectbyname()
{
    string name;
    string word = books.substr(0, string::npos);
    cout << "Введите слово, по которому будет идти поиск" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    word = find(books.begin(), books.end(), name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо заголовки классов `BookShelf` и `Book` увидеть.

Answer (score 1):

Ответы на Ваши вопросы довольно просты. Правда, не знаю, помогут ли они Вам. Тем не менее:

1. *substr: не является членом "std::vector<Book,std::allocator<_Ty>>"* тут ошибка Вам уже всё рассказала, даже сложно что-то добавить. У
   Вас есть вектор книг (видимо, те самые `books`, без заголовка класса
   могу только догадываться). Вектор не имеет метода `substr`, как
   следует хотя бы [отсюда](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).
2. Далее. *не найден оператор "="*. Согласно [этому](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), `find`
   возвращает "итератор на первый элемент, удовлетворяющий условию или
   на последний элемент коллекции, если элементов, удовлетворяющих
   условию, не найдено". Тут первое ключевое слово итератор. Вы
   пытаетесь строке присвоить итератор. Несоответствие типов (как если
   бы Вы попытались числу типа `int` присвоить пременную типа
   `string`). Второе ключевое слово – итератор на **элемент
   коллекции**. У Вас коллекция (вектор) **объектов Book, а не строк**!
   То есть Вы пытаетесь, как минимум, строке присвоить книгу. Тоже
   несоответствие типов.

Если подытожить, все проблемы от того, что Вы пытаетесь работать с вектором `books` сначала так, будто это вообще одна строка, а потом так, будто это вектор строк, хотя `books` ни тем ни другим не является. Это вектор объектов `Book`, и даже если в этих объектах внутри заключена строка, с ними самими как со строками работать нельзя.